# How to use bash to convert a pdf to a png file?

Tags: bash

Hey I'm new to writing bash and would like to make a script that asks a user to enter a pdf file and then converts the pdf to a png file. Is there a simple way to go about doing this? I know to use read command to ask for user input. How would I handle variables and then once the user enters the pdf file location how to change it to a png?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `convert` provided by ImageMagick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use convert command

```
convert file.pdf file.png
```